# Blank initialising an array of structs in C99

Tags: c, struct, initialization, c99

This seems like a hole in my knowledge. As far as I am aware, in C99 if you initialise a single element of a `struct` and no others, the others are zero initialised. Does the following code zero initialise all the members of a `struct` though?

```
typedef struct
{
    int foo;
    int bar;
    char* foos;
    double dar;
} some_struct_t;

some_struct_t mystructs[100] = {};
```

Update: There are some comments indicating that this syntax is an extension. If that is the case, is there any way of doing this that is pure C99 compliant?

Comment: That is an extension of gcc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per `C11`, chapter §6.7.9, Initialization syntax, (*for the sake of completeness, same mentioned in chapter §6.7.8 in `C99`*)

> *initializer:*
>
> assignment-expression
>         { initializer-list }
>         { initializer-list , }
>
> *initializer-list:*
>         designation<sub>opt</sub> initializer
>         initializer-list , designation<sub>opt</sub> initializer
>
> *designation:*
>         designator-list =
>
> *designator-list:*
>         designator
>         designator-list designator
>
> *designator:*
>         [ constant-expression ]
>         . identifier

Which implies, the brace closed initializer list should have at minimum one initializer element (object).

In your code, the empty initializer list

```
 some_struct_t mystructs[100] = {};  //empty list
```

is not a valid pure C syntax; it's a compiler extension.

You need to mention a single element in the list to make it standard conforming, like

```
some_struct_t mystructs[100] = {0};
```

which meets the criteria, from paragraph 21 of same standard(s),

> **If there are fewer initializers in a brace-enclosed list than there are elements or members
>   of an aggregate**, or fewer characters in a string literal used to initialize an array of known
>   size than there are elements in the array, **the remainder of the aggregate shall be
>   initialized implicitly the same as objects that have static storage duration.**

So, in this case, you have one explicit 0 and remaining implicit zero-initialization (or similar).

Comment: I suspect I am being picky here, but that is from C11, is this the same in C99?

Comment: @Joe C has always been like this. The only difference between C standard versions is that C99 introduced designated initializers as one form of explicit initialization.

Answer (score 4):

Because it's array initialisation, you would need

```
some_struct_t mystructs[100] = { 0 }; // ensure all array elements (struct) being zero initialisation
```

Answer (score 4):

For structs/unions (and arrays) there is a rule saying that if it is partially initialized, the rest of the items that didn't get initialized explicitly by the programmer are set to zero.

So by typing `some_struct_t mystructs[100] = {0};` you tell the compiler to explicitly set `foo` to zero. And then the rest of the struct members gets set to zero as well, implicitly.

This has nothing to do with C99, but works for all C standard versions. Although in C99/C11, a designated initializer `{.foo=0}` would have achieved the very same result.