# How can I specify to gcc that {} init in C shouldn't compile?

Tags: c, gcc, c99

with gcc using `-std=gnu99`, the following code compiles:

```
void f()
{
  struct X data = {};
  // do something with data
}
```

Is this valid C ?
Is this a gnu extension ?

How can I tell gcc to not accept this kind of init ?

I want to ensure compatibility with other compilers (like visual 2015 for example)

Comment: What are you trying to do with `{}` ? Initialize the content of `data` ?

Comment: Yes (like { 0 } which is valid C). The problem is that the team uses C++ / C on a daily basis and it is easy for someone to use this without thinking (even if in C++, this would be struct X data {};)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to reject code containing GNU-specific extensions, use `-std=c99 -pedantic-errors` (`-pedantic` will issue diagnostics for non-standard extensions, but it won't necessarily reject the code outright).  However, if you want to guarantee ISO conformance, be aware that this isn't a 100% solution.  From the `gcc` man page:

> Some users try to use `-pedantic` to check programs for strict ISO C conformance.  They soon find that it does not do quite what they want: it finds some non-ISO practices, but not all---only those for which ISO C requires a diagnostic, and some others for which diagnostics have been added.
>
> A feature to report any failure to conform to ISO C might be useful in some instances, but would require considerable additional work and would be quite different from `-pedantic`.  We don't have plans to support such a feature in the near future.

Comment: That being said, gcc compiling with `-std=c11 -pedantic-errors` is probably the most strictly conforming C compiler ever made.

Answer (score 3):

No, the empty initializer is not standard C. It is a gcc extension. [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41889559/2173917) for a detailed description.

By specifying `-std=gnu99`, you allowed the GNU extensions to be used. You can force the compiler to only allow the standard conforming code, by specifying `-std=cXX` option.

From the [gcc online manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Dialect-Options.html#C-Dialect-Options) (*emphasis mine*)

> `-std=`
>
> The compiler can accept several base standards, such as ‘c90’ or ‘c++98’, and GNU dialects of those standards, such as ‘gnu90’ or ‘gnu++98’. **When a base standard is specified, the compiler accepts all programs following that standard plus those using GNU extensions that do not contradict it.** For example, -std=c90 turns off certain features of GCC that are incompatible with ISO C90, such as the asm and typeof keywords, but not other GNU extensions that do not have a meaning in ISO C90, such as omitting the middle term of a ?: expression. On the other hand, **when a GNU dialect of a standard is specified, all features supported by the compiler are enabled, even when those features change the meaning of the base standard.** As a result, some strict-conforming programs may be rejected. The particular standard is used by -Wpedantic to identify which features are GNU extensions given that version of the standard. For example -std=gnu90 -Wpedantic warns about C++ style ‘//’ comments, while -std=gnu99 -Wpedantic does not.

Answer (score 3):

The `-pedantic` option will cause a warning to be displayed in this case, and `-Werror` will cause all warnings to be treated as errors.

For example:

```
x1.c: In function ‘f’:
x1.c:11:19: error: ISO C forbids empty initializer braces [-Werror=pedantic]
   struct X data = {};
```